# Native mobile app deployment for a corporate environment

Tags: android, ios, mobile, deployment

I have a mobile app project where I am trying to decide whether or to go native or web-responsive. The app will have to run on Android and IOS.

My question is about how I would deploy the app to users in a corporate environment.

Do all Android / IOS native apps have to be deployed to the Apple/Google apps stores respectively or is there a way I can create the apps and somehow get them on to my corporate users phones without having them go to the stores?

Apologies in advance if this is dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS you should check out https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise. Having an enterprise developer account allows you to build and distribute apps for internal use.

For Android you could host the APK on an internal server and distribute a link to it for users to download through their browsers. The android browser is smart enough to know what it is and install the program by visiting the link.

This is the most straight forward imo for the users if you don't want to publish it to the store... if you email out the APK you may run into an issue where not everyone sets up corporate email on their phone so you'd have to give those people a direct link to where its hosted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do it on both operating systems.

Typically on the Android side you would simply just put it to the store, but you can setup a server that provides a download link to the APK files that you want to host on your site. Or you can simply setup an e-mail chain.  If the APK files are not too big, then you can simply send out an e-mail with the APK attached to recipients.

Android actually provides for certain channels to be used for internal corporate sharing [Android Private Channel](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

For IOS do you have 2 opstions:

**Apple Developer Account**
https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/

In this account, you would have to submit your application to Apple Store, or use the testflightapp.com / with their certificates (this option you can only register 100 devices to have your app, and experimental certificate in 3 months).

**Enterprise Account**
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/
In this account you need not register the IDs of devices and distribute your app in-house.
If you choose this option, flae that will help me to implement.

Comment: I also found this...https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH12-SW2